# Has many through association with works from console not from controller.

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a problem with a has_many through association.
Somehow u.groups.create!(:name => "test group", :school => "the school") makes a correct insert with the trace:

> (0.1ms)  begin transaction   SQL (4.5ms)  INSERT INTO "groups"
>   ("created_at", "findeble", "name", "school", "updated_at") VALUES (?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 01 Oct 2013 08:13:36 UTC +00:00],
>   ["findeble", false], ["name", "test group"], ["school", "the school"],
>   ["updated_at", Tue, 01 Oct 2013 08:13:36 UTC +00:00]]   SQL (0.3ms) 
>   INSERT INTO "usergroups" ("created_at", "group_id", "updated_at",
>   "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 01 Oct 2013
>   08:13:36 UTC +00:00], ["group_id", 7], ["updated_at", Tue, 01 Oct 2013
>   08:13:36 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]    (0.5ms)  commit transaction 
>   => #

But when I try via the groups_controller

```
    # GET /groups/new
      # GET /groups/new.json
      def new
        @group = current_user.groups.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @group }
        end
      end

  def create
    @group = current_user.groups.new(params[:group])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @group.save
        format.html { redirect_to @group, notice: 'Group was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @group, status: :created, location: @group }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @group.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This creates the trace:

> Started POST "/groups" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-01 10:20:15 +0200
>   Processing by GroupsController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"frETQoB5Mu2gLnIBG644i09XDOHFsEBTGEvrEQmfgPA=",
>   "group"=>{"name"=>"Test group2", "school"=>"Another school",
>   "findeble"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Group"}   User Load (0.2ms) 
>   SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
>   (0.1ms)  begin transaction   SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "groups"
>   ("created_at", "findeble", "name", "school", "updated_at") VALUES (?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 01 Oct 2013 08:20:15 UTC +00:00],
>   ["findeble", true], ["name", "Test group2"], ["school", "Another
>   school"], ["updated_at", Tue, 01 Oct 2013 08:20:15 UTC +00:00]]
>   (6.1ms)  commit transaction

This only creates a new group record and not a record in the joined table. I cant understand what makes this difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `build` method:

```
current_user.groups.build(params[:group])
```

Comment: Hmm. When i do that in the console it behaves just the same as when I do it through the group controller. It skips the join model. But when i use create! it makes makes a record in the joined model.

Comment: Try to save that in console, like: `g = u.groups.build(:name => "test group", :school => "the school")` and then `g.save`

Answer (score 0):

lol007 is right or you can also do it like that

In new action

```
  @group = current_user.groups.build
```

And in create action

```
  @group = current_user.groups.create(params[:group])
```